# Google Sheets - Get value in same cell in previous sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm creating a workout spreadsheet to track my performance week-to-week, with each sheet covering a week's worth of workouts. Each sheet (aside from the first) is a duplicate of the sheet before it, and there are some values I'd like to carry over from the previous sheet; for instance, the number of reps for an exercise from the previous week.

I've read through some of the API but can't seem to find a function that selects the current sheet where the function is called from. If it existed, I could get the index and subtract from it to get the previous sheet, then grab a value from a given row and column. However, the closest thing I can find is accessing the "Active" sheet - something that seems to be set using the setActiveSheet() function. But I don't see how I can use this in a single script meant to be used in multiple different cells.

Am I missing something here, or is there a better way to grab information about the currently-selected sheet? Any help you can provide would be very helpful. Thank you!

[EDIT] My spreadsheet is located here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b8rDYxbb_6ltI0GvKcmKyz1Y3IV3BSrgWp8Mf2l18cc/edit?usp=sharing

Additionally, I will post the script below.

Answer (score 8):

to get the current sheet you can use .getActiveSheet() and then use .getIndex(). Then substract from there. Note that .getIndex() is 1-indexed. So the first sheet will have index 1. If you want to use that in combination with .getSheets() (which is zero-indexed) you will have to do -2 to get to the previous sheet. If needed you may have to build in some error handling (in case you are on the first sheet already). E.g:

```
function previous() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var curSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var prevSheet = ss.getSheets()[curSheet.getIndex() - 2];
prevSheet ? Logger.log(prevSheet.getName()) : SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .alert("Active Sheet is the first sheet !");
}
```

Comment: Hey JPV, thanks for responding. I tried something similar to your function above, but it would always return the value in the first sheet in the spreadsheet. I had thought at first that getActiveSheet() would just refer to the currently-visible sheet, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi again, just tested my code and it seems to log the previous sheet just fine. Maybe there's something in your code responsible for the described behavior ? Would it be possible to share your spreadsheet or your code here ?

Comment: I've tried the code similar to what you've posted, but extended it to take in a row/column, get the range from the previous sheet using the given row/column, and grab the value, then return it. Again, it works fine on the second sheet, but after duplicating the sheet, it again references the values in the first sheet, rather than the second. Is there something wonky about duplicating sheets that may be a factor in this?

Comment: Also, if you take a look at the sheet, please see the getCurrentSheetIndex() function, and notice how no matter which sheet I use it on, it always returns `1`, implying there's something I need to do in order to make certain sheets active.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if you still need them, but I made this script (my dad needed it)

```
function previousCell(cellLocation) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var curSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var curSheetIndex = curSheet.getIndex();
  var preSheetIndex = curSheetIndex - 2;
  var preSheet = ss.getSheets()[preSheetIndex];
  var targetCell = preSheet.getRange(cellLocation);
  var value = targetCell.getValue();
  if (curSheetIndex == 1){
  return "There is no previous sheet" ;
  }

  else    
  return value;
}
```

I have submitted it as Sheets add-on just now, let's see if it will appear soon

Comment: Due to my coding limitation, the cellLocation parameter won't directly address the target cell in the previous sheet

Say your target is A1 in previous 
The first workaround to this is by putting quotation mark in the formula ( =previousCell("A1") )

The second workaround is to have a pointer in other cells (works well for recursion)  i.e. =previousCell(B1), this will read the value of B1 in CURRENT Sheet, 
if B1 in current sheet is empty, it will return an error; so put the target cell of PREVIOUS Sheet ("A1", no need for quotations) in B1

Answer (score 2):

In case this is still of interest, here is my (generic solution):

```js
/**
 * Get name of a given sheet, based on index
 * @param {number}  index          
 *      If positive: See relativeOffset; If negative: A previous sheet (-1 means the one preceeding), otherwise (default) : The current sheet
 * @param {boolean} relativeOffset
 *      If TRUE, a positive index means relative to current sheet tab, otherwise (FALSE=default) absolute sheet index (first is 1)
 * @return The name of the relevant sheet
 * @customfunction
 */
function getSheetName(index,relativeOffset) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var curSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var curSheetIndex = curSheet.getIndex();
  var getSheetIndex = curSheetIndex - 1;
  
if (index > 0 && !relativeOffset)
  {  
   getSheetIndex = index-1;        
  }   else   {
   getSheetIndex = getSheetIndex + index;
  }  
   
  if (index < 0 && !relativeOffset || getSheetIndex < 0)
  {
   return false;
  } 
    
  var getSheet = ss.getSheets()[getSheetIndex];
  //For debugging: 
  //return ("curSheetIndex : " + curSheetIndex + " ; index : "+ index + " ; getSheetIndex : " + getSheetIndex + " ; " + getSheet.getName());
  return getSheet.getName();  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

William's answer works. However when pass the cell location as String for the function parameter for example previousCell("B$1"), when drag and copy the cell, the B$1 will keep the same. To solve this issue, I created another function with relative column location, so it will always access the same row and relative columns from the previous sheet:

```
function previousCell(relCol) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var curSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (curSheet < 2)
    return "There is no previous sheet";
  var preSheet = ss.getSheets()[curSheet.getIndex() - 2];
  var curCel = curSheet.getActiveCell();
  return preSheet.getRange(curCel.getRow(), curCel.getColumn() + relCol).getValue();
}
```

So it will call the function as:  previousCell(2),  it will access the cell with same row and 2 columns right from previous sheet.

Answer (score 1):

A little modification of the answers above:

```js
/**
 * Get value of current cell in previous sheet.
 * Possible to pass reference to any cell
 * Usage: previousSheetCell() or previousSheetCell("B5")
*/

function previousSheetCell(ref1) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var currentSheetIndex = ss.getActiveSheet().getIndex();
  var prevSheet = ss.getSheets()[currentSheetIndex - 2];

  if (!prevSheet) {
    return "No prev sheet";
  }

  if (ref1) {
    return prevSheet.getRange(ref1).getValue()
  }

  var currentCell = sheet.getActiveCell()
  return prevSheet.getRange(currentCell.getRow(), currentCell.getColumn()).getValue();
}
```